# R: Dataframe with occurances of List Objects

Tags: r

I have a List with Vector-Objects in it, which basically looks like this:

```
print(myDocuments)
[[1]]
[1] 4234 3134 1224

[[2]]
 [1] 1234 1312 4123

[[3]]
[1] 1266 4234

[[4]]
[1] 1266 4234 4123 1234
```

So `myDocuments` holds a Vector for every document (4 documents total), each Vector holds a set of hash-codes (simplified by 4-digit int in this example).

What I need now is a `data.frame` or `matrix`, with columns being the documents, and rows being the hash codes of the documents. The data frame should show a 1 if the hash exists in the particular document, and 0 if not, like this:

```
N      D1 D2 D3 D4
1224   1  1  0  1
1234   0  1  0  1
1266   0  0  1  1
3134   1  0  0  0
4234   1  0  1  1
4123   0  1  0  1
```

I really have a hard time getting this done in R, any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(myDocuments))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#1224    1    0    0    0
#1234    0    1    0    1
#1266    0    0    1    1
#1312    0    1    0    0
#3134    1    0    0    0
#4123    0    1    0    1
#4234    1    0    1    1
```